# How to remove the joins in this slow SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have the following (obfuscated) SQL running on `SQL Server 2012` and need to significantly improve its performance. It works, but sometimes takes more than 60s to return.

I would like to extract the `JOINS` but [this post](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-indexed-views/) seems to indicate that this will not be possible (because of things like `MIN` and `MAX`) - so how can improve the performance and get these joins simplified/improved?

```
SELECT
    wm.id, wm.uid, wm.em, wm.fn, wm.ln, c, y, RTRIM(LTRIM(yCode)) AS yCode, wm.d1, ISNULL(wm.ffn, wm.pp) as ffn, wm.ada,
    case
        when wm.mss & 2=2
        then 'false'
        else 'true'
    end AS isa,
    (
        SELECT ', '+RTRIM(p1.cKey)
        FROM profile p1
            inner join loc stl on p1.cKey=stl.cKey
        WHERE p1.id = wm.id and p1.s = 'A'
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) [lst],
    lishc.[lstCount],
    TotalCount = COUNT(*) OVER(),
    la.lsa, wskp.cKey AS pid
FROM wmm wm
    LEFT JOIN profile p1 ON wm.id = p1.id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT UA.id, CONVERT(datetime, UA.ins, 1) As lsa
        FROM actlog UA
            INNER JOIN (
                select id, max(ins) as laa
                from actlog
                group by id
            ) UAJ on UA.id=UAJ.id and UA.ins=UAJ.laa
    ) la on la.id=wm.id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT id, cKey FROM (
            SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY d1 desc) AS ROWNUM 
            FROM keypro where sc = 'SAP' AND cKeyDesc = 'SAP Agent ID'
        ) x WHERE ROWNUM = 1
    ) wskp ON wskp.id = wm.id
    LEFT JOIN (
        (SELECT p1.id ,COUNT(p1.cKey) AS [lstCount]
        FROM profile p1
            inner join loc stl on p1.cKey=stl.cKey
        where p1.s = 'A'
        GROUP BY p1.id)
    ) lishc ON lishc.id = wm.id
WHERE (@id = 0 OR wm.id = @id)
    AND (@uid IS NULL OR wm.uid LIKE '%' + @uid + '%')
    AND (@c IS NULL OR wm.c LIKE '%' + @c + '%')
    AND (@fn IS NULL OR wm.fn LIKE '%' + @fn + '%')
    AND (@ln IS NULL OR wm.ln LIKE '%' + @ln + '%')
    AND (@em IS NULL OR wm.em LIKE '%' + @em + '%')
    AND (@ffn IS NULL OR (wm.ffn LIKE '%' + @ffn + '%' OR wm.pp LIKE '%' + @ffn + '%'))                                                                
    AND (@pid IS NULL OR wskp.cKey LIKE '%' + @pid + '%' )
    AND (@Date1 IS NULL OR (CAST(wm.d1 AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(@Date1 AS DATE) AND CAST(@Date2 AS DATE)))
    AND (@lsa1 IS NULL OR (CAST(la.lsa AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(@lsa1 AS DATE) AND CAST(@lsa2 AS DATE)))
    AND (@Active IS NULL OR (wm.mss & 2 != 2))
    AND (@Inactive IS NULL OR (wm.mss & 2 = 2))
    AND (@External IS NULL OR (wm.ada = 'biz'))
    AND (@Internal IS NULL OR (wm.ada <> 'biz'))
    AND (@ApplyyFilter =0  OR (wm.yCode IN (SELECT @yCode WHERE 1 = 0))) 
    AND (@ApplylstFilter = 0 OR(p1.cKey IN (SELECT @ShipToList WHERE 1 = 0)))
    AND (@ApplylstFilter = 0 OR(p1.s = 'A'))
    AND (@ApplyNoFilter = 0 OR (lishc.[lstCount] is null))
    AND (@lstCount = 0 OR lishc.[lstCount] = @lstCount)
    AND (@ApplyLimitedFilter = 0 OR (wm.id IN (0)))
    AND (@ApplyMoreFilter = 0 OR (wm.id IN (SELECT @idss WHERE 1 = 0)))
GROUP BY wm.id, wm.uid, wm.em, wm.fn, wm.ln, y, yCode,c,wm.d1,wm.ffn,wm.mss,wm.ada, la.lsa, wskp.cKey, lishc.[lstCount], wm.pp
ORDER BY lsa DESC
OFFSET @PageOffset ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: You have the problem here of having a catch-all query, which require different logic. Plus almost *every single one* of your parameters are wrapped in wild cards, making the query completely non-SARGable. I suspect that the JOINs are one of the smaller problems here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quick hit here is to add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` so SQL Server can eliminate the predicates that correspond to null parameters and create a new plan for each search.

And see, generally [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

The next thing to do is to get rid of the wildcard searches wherever possible.

And transform this

```
 (CAST(la.lsa AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(@lsa1 AS DATE) AND CAST(@lsa2 AS DATE)))
```

into a SARGable pattern like

```
 la.lsa >= @lsa1 and la.lsa < @lsa2
```

Then start to pull this query apart, and hand-write separate queries for the most common or critical cases.

Comment: +1 for `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`. SQL Server will then use constant folding to eliminate predicates where the result is known at compile time.

Comment: Why would `BETWEEN` be non-sargable? [This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) explicitly lists it as SARGable.

Comment: The `BETWEEN` is fine (although the replacement should be `>=` and `<=`), but the `CAST`s make it non-SARGable.

Comment: And the change from between to >=, < is because  lsa might have a time component, so @lsa2 would be midnight on the next day.

Comment: Let's say @lsa1 = '12 Nov 2020 15:30' and @lsa2 = '19 Nov 2020 10:01' then the original query would allow for '19 Nov 2020 18:05' to match but the `>=` / `<` clause will not! So even though I hadn't realised it yesterday, the replacement is NOT equivalent when the data has time-parts... All in all, the problem here is mainly that we don't know the datatype of `lsa`, `@lsa1` and `@lsa2`. For all we know it could be strings with ISO 106 notation thus actually requiring the `CAST()`. Fun fact: if they are `datetime`s then the `Cast` to `date` will NOT break SARGability if I remember correctly.

Comment: The parameters would need to be adjusted.